# ARWorldMap lighting conditions

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit, arworldmap

I use ARWorldMap to save the state of the scene and restore it later. I use the code recommended by Apple in the examples. There is a problem: lighting conditions, if I record a map of the world in a room with bright lighting, it is impossible to restore the position of the content in medium light, and in reverse order it is analgesic.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this so that the lighting conditions do not affect the recovery of the session with the world map?

Answer (score 0):

Save & load lighting parameters retrieving ARKit's [Light Estimation](https://medium.com/macoclock/arkit-911-light-estimation-e10adf49ab32) values. However, if you want AR app can recognize different lighting conditions of some environment you should generate `.mlmodel` based on several hundreds of images (using Create ML app) and feed it to Vision SDK for [classification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/classifying_images_for_categorization_and_search). Although, to be honest, I highly doubt that a Vision approach will be working sanely. So for accuracy, you may use light estimation parameters' values in conjunction with Vision's classification results. You need to try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't work in my case, I need the scene from initialWorldmap to be recognized in any lighting conditions (except for very dark ones), but ARKit can't recognize a scene recorded in different lighting conditions. I tried disabling isLightEstimationEnabled, but it didn't help. Do lighting conditions affect Scene Understanding so much? Maybe there are other options?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a device with LiDAR it should be possible to regenerate the World Map in other lightning conditions. I have the same issue like you and I am working on it. I still don't have a clear solution at the moment. I've also contacted Apple on this, without any succes (no documents or demo's). If I know how to solve this I let you know.